# How can I manage translated model fields in GORM?

Tags: go, database-design, go-gorm

I need to translate an arbitrary number of fields from a go-gorm model to an arbitrary number of languages.

I'm studying the best database/model layout to do that.

Options that I have in mind:

1. Keep translated fields as a model field -> Every new language will involve model modification, I will also create a potentially wide table depending on number of languages and fields to translate. Query a given language might not be easy. Seems the worst one

```golang
type Product {
....
EN_description string
DE_description string
....
}
```

2. Create a ProductTranslation Relation for each field to translate

```golang
type Product {
....
Descriptions []ProductDescTranslation
....
}

type ProductDescTranslation {
Language string
ProductID uint
Value string
}
```

3. Create a single ProductTranslation Relation -> This one seems more generic than number 2 since I don't need a different relation for each field but also seems to include more complexity since its not obvious how many translated fields the Product model has unless you run a query against that table.

```golang
type Product {
....
Translations []ProductTranslation
....
}

type ProductTranslation {
Language string
ProductID uint
Field string
Value string
}
```

Anyone has better ideas? Does anyone know about any package already coded for that purpose? I did not find one.

Comment: Have you found a solution, I want to achieve the same?